# C Dynamic Memory Allocation in Struct pointers

Tags: c, pointers, struct, dynamic-memory-allocation

I am unfamiliar with C language and I'm performing on a task related to the C-language structure pointer. I have to be input in the order of `date((yyyyMMdd) time(hhmm) name(title) importance(1~10) content.` It must be output in the order of `date (yyyy.MM.dd.) time (hh:mm) importance content.`
and here is my code. This code generates C4047, C4024 errors on the 27,28th line. and If I ignore the error message and debug it, an error of 'wntdll.pdb not loaded' is occur. what should i do?

````
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct Calender
{
    int day, time;
    int imt; //importance
    char tle[127]; //title
    char cnt[127]; //contents
};
void input_calender()
{
    char title[127];
    char contents[127];
    struct Calender* a = malloc(sizeof(struct Calender));
    scanf("%d", &(a->day));
    scanf("%d", &(a->time));
    scanf("%d", &(a->imt));
    scanf("%hhd", &title);
    scanf("%hhd", &contents);

    a->day = 8;
    a->time = 4;
    a->imt = 1;
    strcpy(a->tle, &title);
    strcpy(a->cnt, &contents);

    free(a);
}
void print_calender(struct Calender* a)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {
        if (i == 4 || i == 6)
            printf(".");
        printf("%c", ((a->day) + i));
    }
    printf(" ");
    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        if (i == 2)
            printf(":");
        printf("%c", ((a->time) + i));
    }
    printf(" ");

    printf("%d ", a->imt);
    printf("%s ", a->tle);
    printf("%s\n ", a->cnt);
}
int main(void) {
    int num=0;
    int i;
    struct Calender* p = malloc(sizeof(struct Calender) * (num + 1));
    scanf("%d", &num);
    //입력 
    for (i = 0; i < num; i++)
    {
        input_calender(p + i);
    }
    //출력 
    for (i = 0; i < num; i++)
    {
        print_calender(p + i);
    }
    free(p);

} ```
````

Comment: you are allocating stuff before knowing how may entries you have; that said there are quite a lots of other problems, try avtivate warnings on you compiler and fix any warning is a good start.

Comment: Note that when the name of an array is used, it is converted to the address of its first element. So instead of `strcpy(a->tle, &title);` use `strcpy(a->tle, title);` (since `title` is an array so is already an address).

Comment: `input_calender(p + i);` but `input_calender` is defined as having no parameters (actually, any number of parameters, but the function can't access them).